# Issue when convert buffer to string with hexadecimal code of LF

Tags: java, android, string, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I am trying to download web page with all its resources . First i download the html, but when to be sure to keep file formatted and use this function below .
there is and issue , i found 10 in the final file and when i found that hexadecimal code of the LF or line escape . and this makes troubles to my javascript functions .

Example of the final result :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>10<html lang="fr">10 <head>10    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />10
```

Can someone help me to found the real issue  ?

```
public static String  scanfile(File file) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            while (true) {
                String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (readLine != null) {
                    sb.append(readLine);
                    sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    Log.i(TAG,sb.toString());
                } else {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return sb.toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear, what do you get in output, the string "10" or the LF (10) character?

Comment: I get the string 10  instead of LF . Please check the final result as printed

Comment: You want to download the webpage. Ok. And then? What are you doing with the downloaded page? Saving to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no problem in this function I was mistakenly adding 10 using another function in my code .

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with your code.

### Charset error

> `BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));`

This isn't going to work in tricky ways.

Files (and, for that matter, data given to you by webservers) comes in bytes. A stream of numbers, each number being between 0 and 255.

So, if you are a webserver and you want to send the character `ö`, what byte(s) do you send?

The answer is complicated. The mapping that explains how some character is rendered in byte(s)-form is called a **character set encoding** (shortened to 'charset').

Anytime bytes are turned into characters or vice versa, **there is always a charset involved**. Always.

So, you're reading a file (that'd be bytes), and turning it into a Reader (which is chars). Thus, charset is involved.

Which charset? The API of `new FileReader(path)` explains which one: "The system default". **You do not want that**.

Thus, this code is broken. You want one of two things:

### Option 1 - write the data as is

When doing the job of querying the webserver for the data and relaying this information onto disk, you'd want to just store the bytes (after all, webserver gives bytes, and disks store bytes, that's easy), but the webserver *also* sends the encoding, in a header, and you need to save this separately. Because to *read* that 'sack of bytes', you need to know the charset to turn it into characters.

How would you do this? Well, up to you. You could for example decree that the data file starts with the name of a charset encoding (as sent via that header), then a `0` byte, and then the data, unmodified. I think you should go with option 2, however

### Option 2

Another, better option for text-based documents (which HTML is), is this: When reading the data, convert it to characters, using the encoding as that header tells you. Then, to save it to disk, turn the chars back to bytes, using UTF-8, which is a great encoding and an industry standard. That way, when reading, you just know it's UTF-8, period.

To read a UTF-8 text file, you do:

```
Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file));
```

The reason this works, is that the `Files` API, unlike most other APIs (and unlike FileReader, which you **should never ever use**), defaults to UTF_8 and not to platform-default. If you want, you can make it more readable:

```
Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

same thing - but now in the code it is clear what's happening.

### Broken exception handling

> ```
> } catch (IOException e) {
>   e.printStackTrace();
>   return null;
> }
> ```

This is not okay - if you catch an exception, either [A] throw something else, or [B] handle the problem. And 'log it and keep going' is definitely not 'handling' it. Your strategy of exception handling results in 1 error resulting in a thousand things going wrong with a thousand stack traces, and all of them except the first are undesired and irrelevant, hence why this is horrible code and you should never write it this way.

The easy solution is to just put `throws IOException` on your `scanFile` method. The method inherently interacts with files, it SHOULD be throwing that. Note that your `psv main(String[] args)` method can, and usually should, be declared to `throws Exception`.

It also makes your code simpler and shorter, yay!

### Resource Management failure

a filereader is a resource. You **MUST** close it, no matter what happens. You are not doing that: If `.readLine()` throws an exception, then your code will jump to the catch handler and `bufferedReader.close` is never executed.

The solution is to use the ARM (Automatic Resource Management) construct:

```
try (var br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    // code goes here
}
```

This construct ensures that `close()` is invoked, regardless of how the 'code goes here' block exits. Even if it 'exits' via an exception or a `return` statement.

### The problem

Your 'read a file and print it' code is other than the above three items mostly fine. The problem is that the HTML file on disk is corrupted; the error lies in your code that reads the data from the web server and saves it to disk. You did not paste that code.

Specifically, `System.lineSeparator()` returns the actual string. Thus, assuming the code you pasted really is the code you are running, if you are seeing an actual '10' show up, then that means the HTML file on disk has that in there. It's not the read code.

### Closing thoughts

More generally the job of 'just print a file on disk with a known encoding' can be done in far fewer lines of code:

```
public static String scanFile(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.readString(Paths.get(path));
}
```

You should just use the above code instead. It's simple, short, doesn't have any bugs, cannot leak resources, has proper exception handling, and will use UTF-8.

Comment: I afraid Your solution didn't work i got 10 everywhere ! it's not an issue of UTF-8 by default android's encoding is UTF-8 . when i write the file  from bytes to string LF bytes get ignored and i don't know why ! that's the main issue .

Comment: Read more carefully then - the answer specifically calls out there is an issue in the code that fetched the HTML from the server, which you didn't paste.

Comment: Actually it's been a while, and I forgot to make an answer. I need to mention that my function works but the 10 was injected by another function.